# Адаптивная верстка

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, вёрстка

Нужно что-бы блок не показывался если размер браузера меньше чем 1200px. Попробовал через [[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) вот так:

```
@media screen and (width: 1200px) {
.mCSB_scrollTools { display:none !imporatnt; }
}
```

Но не работает, я думаю я неправильно составил условие. Подскажите какое лучше использовать?

Comment: так ?

    @media screen and (max-width: 1199px)
      .mCSB_scrollTools { display:none !imporatnt; }
     }

Comment: нет не работает, даже окно выставить 600 px

Comment: Попробуй так
`@media (max-width: 1200px)
{
    .mCSB_scrollTools { display:none !important; }

}`

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере `!important` написано с ошибкой.

Откройте сниплет на всю страницу и меняйте её размер, при уменьшении окна до 800 пикселей текст исчезает.

```css
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
.mCSB_scrollTools { display:none; }
}
```

```html
<div class=mCSB_scrollTools>Пропадающий блок</div>
```